# Android 9 phone don't connect to USB on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, android, phone

Once a day Android 9 stop mount to Ubuntu 18.04. I've find errors in `dmesg`, please find it below. And `lsusb` don't show USB device connected. Can anyone help me to connect it?

```
$ dmesg
...
[161812.841461] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 73 using ehci-pci
[161812.921476] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[161813.109509] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[161813.297468] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 74 using ehci-pci
[161813.377455] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[161813.565511] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[161813.673527] usb 2-1-port3: attempt power cycle
[161814.277491] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 75 using ehci-pci
[161814.693500] usb 2-1.3: device not accepting address 75, error -32
[161814.777491] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 76 using ehci-pci
[161815.193484] usb 2-1.3: device not accepting address 76, error -32
[161815.193700] usb 2-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
$ lsusb
```

Comment: Did you check the USB Options on your phone? Try altering the option (MTP/ PTP/ charge only/ USB debugging).